# SQL Sum multiple rows by ID //For use in SP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am Back once Again :)

i did look to see if there were other questions like the one i am about to ask but they are using joins from different tables where as i have my data inside one table and do not require any joins, i am not really that good when it comes to SQL so where this might be simple to you, it is rather complex to me so here we go

i have 1 #table that returns a value called LineTotal which is a sum of UnitPrice and TranDespQty, alright so every InvoiceNo has got Multiple TranLineNo, one for each Item so what i need is the InvoiceTotal to be the sum of Every LineTotal for the Invoice if that makes sense

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_PPEInvEnquiry_Invoice_Summary @InvoiceNoFrom int, 
   @InvoiceNoTo int
   as
    if object_id ('tempdb..#tranData2') is not null 
     drop table #tranData2
     select c.Extra2 as InvoiceNo,
       c.TranLineNo,
       cast(null as varchar(255)) as TranDate,
       cast(null as varchar(255)) as AssetName,
       b.ItemCode,
       cast(0 as Decimal(18,2)) as UnitPrice,
       b.TranDespQty,
       cast(0 as Decimal(18,2)) as LineTotal,   
       cast(0 as Decimal(18,2)) as InvoiceTotal

       into #tranData2 
   from TS_TranHeader a, TS_TranDetail b ,
   (select distinct TranDocNo, TranLineNo, TranSlipNo, ItemCode, CoyCode, Extra2 
   from TS_TranSlip where TranSlipScanned = 'P')  c,
   (Select CoyCode,StoreCode,StoreName From TS_Store Where CoyCode = 'KWV') d
   where a.TranDocNo = b.TranDocNo 
   and a.TranDocNo = c.TranDocNo 
   and a.CoyCode = c.CoyCode 
   and a.CoyCode = b.CoyCode 
   and a.CoyCode = 'KWV' 
   and b.TranLineNo = c.TranLineNo
   and a.StoreCode = d.StoreCode

   update a 
   set AssetName = b.AssetName
   from #tranData2 a, TW_Asset b --updates the AssetName and AssetCode 

   update a --updates the trandate
   set a.TranDate = b.TranDate
   from #tranData2 a,TS_TranHeader b
   where a.InvoiceNo -100 = b.TranDocNo

   update a
   set    a.UnitPrice = b.ItemSellingPrice
   from #tranData2 a, TS_Item b, TS_Store d
   where  a.ItemCode = b.ItemCode 

   update a
   set LineTotal = UnitPrice * TranDespQty
   from #tranData2 a
```

there is an Idea on what my table looks like and below is a screen shot of the columns i am talking about

https://prnt.sc/qs7r1f

the red is all the Invoice Numbers that are the same Invoice Blue is the Line Total that needs to be Summed and added to black with is the InvoiceTotal For invoice number (in this case) 137

Comment: You really, REALLY, should stop using old-style joins via the where clause. Your first update statement is logically flawed. You cross-joined _#tranData2_ and TW_Asset - the value assigned to AssetName will simply be pulled from one of those rows but you have no control over which. Small tables and lightly loaded server might provide the illusion that the query works - don't be fooled. Note also your comment is wrong - AssetCode is NOT updated nor does it exist in the table. Incorrect comments are worse than no comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after about an hour or so of searching other forums and rewording my question i think i got the answer

```
select InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate, AssetName,sum(LineTotal)as TotalInvoiceValue,WeekNumber
from #tranData2
where InvoiceNo >= @InvoiceNoFrom
and InvoiceNo <= @InvoiceNoTo 
group by InvoiceNo, InvoiceDate, AssetName,WeekNumber
```